# php foreach issue in multiple file upload

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to save files from a file upload which has more than one file using a foreach loop. But the move_uploaded_file is only executing once. I tried printing $file['tmp_name'], but it's printing two array values in one single line as text. How can fix this .. Thanks ..

```
  public function uploadFile($filename)
    {

        $file_ary = $this->reArrayFiles($_FILES[$filename]);

        foreach ($file_ary as $file) {

           move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'] , '../uploads/' . '.txt');

        }




    }


   function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {
        $file_ary = array();
        if(!is_array($file_post['name']))
            return array($file_post);
        $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
        $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
                $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            }
        }
        return $file_ary;
    }


 $file_ary :- Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => customer care.txt [type] =>     text/plain [tmp_name] => C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer- 14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\php7B21.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 11 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => ss.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\php7B32.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )

$file['tmp_name']  : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-     14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\phpA38A.tmpC:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer- 14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\phpA38B.tmp
```

[image]

Comment: Paste your `$file_ary` here

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\phpA38A.tmpC:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\phpA38B.tmp ... literally i am expecting an array , but it's showing plain text with no separator..

Comment: Looks like string.Is this an `array`?

Comment: Consider doing the following in order to debug it: 1) `echo $file['error'];` in order to check if an error occurred during the upload. 2) `$res = move_uplo..; var_dump($res)` to check if an error occurred during the upload. Share with us the output of them both.

Comment: see my updated post :) The one i posted in the comment is the output i got from inside the foreach .. I am using the foreach for saving the multiple files to the destination folder .. Thanks

Comment: @OfirBaruch File uploaded succesfully , but only one file.. I am uploading more than one at a time

Comment: We are trying to debug what it's not uploading the other files, don't we? Therefore, we need to check firstly if all the files are being uploaded, after that - if they're not being uploaded - why (the `2` debug).

Comment: yeah it's working see when i print the $file , i am getting this : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\phpA38A.tmpC:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\tmp\phpA38B.tmp .. 2 files uploaded 2 temp files created . But the script is saving only one ..

Answer (score 1):

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.

Taken from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Basically, after you move it, the file will no longer exist. Note, that move differs from copy in the fact that it removes the source file. You need to create a file resource, copy the needed content there and then save it wherever and whenever you want.

Comment: I can see only one file in the saved directory. I am expecting more than one file . The move_uploaded function is only executing once .. Thanks though

Comment: OK, let me put it this way: you want to save file1 and file2. When you call move_uploaded_file for file1, then file1 is successfully created, but the source file is DELETED. When you call it for file2, the source file no longer exists, hence you can no longer move it. This is why I suggested that you should create an image resource and save it instead of your current (wrong) strategy.